# change text size in view pager fragment according seek bar in activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-seekbar, text-size

In my activity [(Please see image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMEA4.png), I have seek bar and view pager ( have 3 pages).

I want so that, when seek bar in activity change, the text of the fragment size also varies.

How can I do it?

I try it with interface but it not run.

**Mainactivity**

```
package com.creativei.viewpagerloop;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "ViewPagerLoop";

    public static final String[] content = new String[] {
            "Hello Welcome to ViewPager Loop Example. This is first view. Swipe right â†’ for second view, swipe left â†� for last view.",
            "Awesome, now you are on second view. Swipe right â†’ again to go to last view.",
            "Finally made it to last view, swipe right â†’ again to go to first view." };
    Interface inter;

    public MainActivity(Interface inter) {
        this.inter = inter;
    }

    private SeekBar seekBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        TextView counter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.counter);
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {
                inter.seekBarChange(progress);
            }

            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }

            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });

        SimpleViewPagerAdapter adapter = new SimpleViewPagerAdapter(
                getSupportFragmentManager(), pager, content, counter);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);
        pager.setOnPageChangeListener(adapter);
        pager.setCurrentItem(1, false);
    }

    public static class SimpleFragment extends Fragment implements Interface {
        private TextView textView;

        public SimpleFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            String content = getArguments().getString("content");
            textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.content);
            textView.setText(content);
            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void seekBarChange(int id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            textView.setTextSize(id);
        }
    }

    public static class SimpleViewPagerAdapter extends
            FragmentStatePagerAdapter implements OnPageChangeListener {

        private String[] content;
        private ViewPager pager;
        private TextView counter;

        public SimpleViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ViewPager pager,
                String[] content, TextView counter) {
            super(fm);
            this.pager = pager;
            this.content = content;
            this.counter = counter;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            SimpleFragment fragment = new SimpleFragment();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            int index = position;

            bundle.putString("content", content[index]);
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return content.length;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        }

        private String makeCounterText(int pageNo) {
            return "Page " + pageNo + " of " + content.length;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

    }
}
```

**Interface**

```
package com.creativei.viewpagerloop;

public interface Interface {
    public void seekBarChange(int id);
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.creativei.viewpagerloop.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/counter"
        android:layout_below="@+id/seekBar1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/counter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**fragment_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.creativei.viewpagerloop.SimpleFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please describe you problem in further detail? I am going to assume you are having difficulty properly articulating your problem in English; and request it be edited.

Comment: in my activity have a seek bar and a view pager
I custom a fragment and use it to display the page in view pager
In the fragment I have a TextView
Now I want to increase or decrease seek bar, the font size of textview in the fragment is increased or decreased. You can help me?
sorry about the possibility of my presentation, I use google translate

Comment: Please add that information to your actual question.

Answer (score 0):

You can get reference from this example http://sampleprogramz.com/android/seekbar.php

Comment: problem I encountered here was progressbar in activity and TextView in fragment view pager , they are not the same file.xml as your link